# Losslessly encode png frames to webm with ffmpeg

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, png, webm

I need to convert a directory of frames to webm with absolutely no image compression, just raw images-to-frames. Using ffmpeg version N-82889-g54931fd, this is what I'm at right now.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -f image2 -i frames/%02d.png -pix_fmt yuva420p -crf 0 output.webm
```

The crf 0 flag was told to be the answer, but the output is still full of compression and artifacts. Is there an option to make each frame as close to identical as possible to their corresponding png image frame?

Comment: Have you tried `-lossless 1` for encoder? btw, I guess `yuva420p` has ensured the video is lossy.

Comment: i thought yuva420p was required for webm encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VP8, default encoder for WebM, does not have a lossless mode. Use VP9.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i frames/%02d.png -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuva420p -lossless 1 out.webm
```

Note that due to the pixel format conversion (RGB -> YUV), output will not be perfectly lossless, as there will be some rounding errors when decoding back to RGB.